# How do I create a simple Vue project without a big app.js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, babeljs

I want to create a Vue app, so I started by using the Vue CLI to do so, but the app.js bundle is 1.2 MB before I've even really done anything. I'd like to bring that way down, as I really don't want/need all the stuff that is being bundled into that file.

Specifically, I would like to have a Vue app with Babel so I can transpile ES6, Webpack for bundling everything, and Sass for the CSS.

What's the easiest way to create a Vue project like this without all the bloat that occurs when I use the Vue CLI? And what I'm specifically looking for is instructions on how to install (I'm assuming just use npm) all of these things and then setting them up to work together, which is the part I'm stuck on.

I can set up Webpack by itself, and I can set up Vue by itself, but I don't know how to get Webpack to compile Vue files, and I don't know how to set up Babel to work with all of this and transpile everything. Thank you.

Comment: You mean you are getting a 1.2MB bundle after running `npm run build` on a brand new CLI app? I am unable to reproduce that, I'm getting 5KB app + 83KB chunk-vendors.

Comment: I did the default setup for Vue CLI (maybe that's part of the problem), and then `npm run serve`, and the app.js file (I'm assuming it's in dev mode) is 1.2 MB.

Comment: the serve command uses webpack-dev-server and offers hot-reloading of your files. It is naturally a lot bigger than the production build. Also, the included webpack config already uses babel to transpile ES6. If you install node-sass and sass-loader you also get to use sass without further config.

Comment: All right. That sounds like the way to go then. I guess I was just misunderstanding how the Vue CLI bundled everything together. Thank you.